# WPF Styling: BasedOn template but change 2 difference background colours

Tags: wpf

I have got a button with a ControlTemplate, this ControlTemplate has 2 different Control's with different background colours. I want to be able to change these colours using a new style which is BasedOn this main style.

Read the code and it should make more sense. For some reason though the new `Style.Resources` are not changing the background colours, they are still using the two defined in the main style.

How can I fix this?

```
Style BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonIcoSmall}" TargetType="Button" x:Key="greenSmallButton">
            <Style.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF8AB71C" x:Key="colour1" />
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF72A000" x:Key="colour2" />
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>

        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonIcoSmall}" TargetType="Button" x:Key="greySmallButton">
            <Style.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF434953" x:Key="colour1" />
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF22252b" x:Key="colour2" />
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="ButtonIcoSmall" TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF434953" x:Key="colour1" />
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF22252b" x:Key="colour2" />
            </Style.Resources>

            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource FontAwesome}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="6" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextFormattingMode" Value="Display" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <WrapPanel>
                            <Border Grid.Column="0"
                                    CornerRadius="5 0 0 5" 
                                    BorderThickness="0"
                                    Background="{StaticResource colour1}"
                                    Name="buttonIcon">
                                <WrapPanel>
                                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" 
                                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                                      VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}" />
                                </WrapPanel>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.Column="0"
                                    CornerRadius="0 5 5 0" 
                                    BorderThickness="0"
                                    Background="{StaticResource colour2}"
                                    Name="buttonText" >
                                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}" 
                                                       FontSize="13"
                                                       Foreground="White"
                                                       Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
                            </Border>
                        </WrapPanel>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding ElementName=buttonIcon}" TargetName="buttonText" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="#757b8d" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />-->
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. You should move you main style above the derived styles. If you use `BasedOn` before the style that its basing itself on, it will not find it.
2. For the colors that you are changing, use a `DynamicResource` instead. This allows the two colors to be re-defined instead of using the defaults.

I got it working using the following code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        x:Name="TestWindow">
    <Window.Resources>

        <Style x:Key="ButtonIcoSmall" TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF434953" x:Key="colour1" />
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF22252b" x:Key="colour2" />
            </Style.Resources>

            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource FontAwesome}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="6" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextFormattingMode" Value="Display" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <WrapPanel>
                            <Border Grid.Column="0"
                                    CornerRadius="5 0 0 5" 
                                    BorderThickness="0"
                                    Background="{DynamicResource colour1}"
                                    Name="buttonIcon">
                                <WrapPanel>
                                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" 
                                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                                      VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}" />
                                </WrapPanel>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.Column="0"
                                    CornerRadius="0 5 5 0" 
                                    BorderThickness="0"
                                    Background="{DynamicResource colour2}"
                                    Name="buttonText" >
                                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}" 
                                                       FontSize="13"
                                                       Foreground="White"
                                                       Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
                            </Border>
                        </WrapPanel>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding ElementName=buttonIcon}" TargetName="buttonText" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="#757b8d" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />-->
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonIcoSmall}" TargetType="Button" x:Key="greenSmallButton">
            <Style.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF8AB71C" x:Key="colour1" />
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF72A000" x:Key="colour2" />
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>

        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonIcoSmall}" TargetType="Button" x:Key="greySmallButton">
            <Style.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF434953" x:Key="colour1" />
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF22252b" x:Key="colour2" />
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource greenSmallButton}"/>
</Window>
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, didn't think to put them under the main style -_-